# How to filter shift +/- 1 day in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have timeseries data. How to filter data that only occurs in 1 days different?

Suppose the data is

```
date         name
2015-04-03    A
2015-04-04    A
2015-04-05    A
2015-04-03    B
```

What I want to do is something like

```
df[df.shift(1).contains(df.name) or df.shift(-1).contains(df.name)]
```

that would give me

```
date         name
2015-04-03    A
2015-04-04    A
2015-04-05    A
```

How to do this in pandas?

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches or whether 'name' really does 'contain' the current row 'name' value

Comment: I don't understand the question, but it seems you want to use `groupby('name')` here and then whatever else you are trying to do.  Maybe this?  `df.groupby('name')['date'].apply( lambda x: x == x.shift() + datetime.timedelta(1) )`

Comment: This is a very confusing question, why does it have 5 upvotes?!?  The description, code, and results are all different from each other.  This should really be clarified by the OP if there is this much interest in the question and answers.

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it in pandas. Of course the code is incorrect. I won't be asking here in the first place.

Consider the dataframe as login log files.The problem is that I'm trying to filter to allow users that occurs in the next day, as dataframe. I'm accepting EdChum's answer, since it filtered the users B. 

the example results that EdChum gave is correct. The incorrect result is from my end. I will fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to wrap your conditions in parentheses and use the bitwise `|` instead of `or`:

```
In [83]:
df[(df['name'].shift(1) == df['name']) | (df['name'].shift(-1) == df['name']) ]

Out[83]:
        date name
0 2015-04-03    A
1 2015-04-04    A
2 2015-04-05    A
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use value_counts for date:

```
vc = df.date.value_counts()
```

Then I would, if the dataset is small, I would use `.isin`:

```
df[df.date.isin(vc[vc == 1].index.tolist())]

         date name
1  2015-04-04    A
2  2015-04-05    A
```

If the dataset is larger, I would use the merge operation:

```
df_singles = df.merge(left_on='date',right=pd.DataFrame(vc[vc == 1]), right_index=True)
del df_singles[0]

         date name
1  2015-04-04    A
2  2015-04-05    A
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert you date column to datetime object. Then you can calculate the difference between days. After that, you can filter for the number of days difference you want to retain

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data['Diff'] = data['date'].diff()
print data

        date name    Diff
0 2015-04-03    A     NaT
1 2015-04-04    A  1 days
2 2015-04-05    A  1 days
3 2015-04-03    B -2 days

data_filtered = data[data['Diff'] == '1 days']
del data_filtered['Diff']
print data_filtered

        date name
1 2015-04-04    A
2 2015-04-05    A
```